# HashMap get method in Java 6 & Java 8

Tags: java

I am looking at HashMap get method in Java 6 & Java 8, the implementation in Java 8 is little complex, I am not able to get it.

This is from [Java 6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.get%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public V get(Object key) {
    if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here in Java 6, it is getting the right Entry element and trying to find the corresponding value based on given key.

This code if from [Java 8](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.get%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
    public V get(Object key) {
        Node<K,V> e;
        return (e = getNode(hash(key), key)) == null ? null : e.value;
    }

 final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {

     Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;

     if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
            (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {

            if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
                ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k)))) {
                return first;
            }

            if ((e = first.next) != null) {

                if (first instanceof TreeNode) {
                    return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
                }

                do {
                    if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k)))) {
                        return e;
                    }
                } while ((e = e.next) != null);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am not able to understand the logic in Java 8.

How they are taking the first element:

```
 (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null)
```

and what is this extra logic:

```
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
```

Comment: Have you read the implementation notes in the source code you've linked to? It explains pretty clearly what it is and why it is that.

Comment: @biziclop, are you referring to the notes related to get method? There is no explanation given for this method about the new changes. Can you please tell me which one you are referring to?

Comment: No, at the top of the class there is a long comment entitled "Implementation notes", where they explain the entire `TreeNode` business.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

```
(first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null)
```

That comes from how the entry is added to the table, shown below:

```
if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
    tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
```

AND-ing (n-1) and hash allows entries with hashCode=hash to be spread over the n entries of the table. (n-1) is used to prevent the edge case of attempting to insert into tab[n] - which could lead to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException since tab.length is n.

The "extra logic" that you are referring to:

```
if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
    ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
    return first;
```

The above returns the very first Node from the table which not only matches the hashCode of the key being searched, but also exactly "equals" that key.

```
if ((e = first.next) != null) {
    if (first instanceof TreeNode)
        return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
```

The above returns the Node if the bucket has been "Treeified" - details about which as pointed in one of the comments is specified in the "Implementation Notes" of this class.